# SplClassLoader Directory Structure

Tags: php, namespaces, spl-autoloader

I am new to namespaces and I guess autoloading in the method of SplClassLoader. I've tried search for many tutorials but not having much luck. Perhaps you guys can help me get this going?

**Directory Structure**

```
- Oram
    - Lib
        - Classes
            Test.php
- index.php
- SplClassLoader.php
```

**Test.php**

```
<?php
namespace Oram\Lib\Classes;

class Test
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo "Test Class loaded";
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once('SplClassLoader.php');

$loader = new SplClassLoader('Lib', 'Oram\Lib'); 
$loader->register();

use Oram\Lib\Classes\Test;
$test = new Test();
```

This is all inside localhost/website/ too btw as I am running it on WAMP.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Oram\Lib\Classes\Test' not found in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\website\index.php on line 10
```

Any advice or if someone could point me to some reading resources to get my head around this would be great.

Thank you

Comment: ***Which*** `SplClassLoader` class are you referring to in your question?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** 
    I have it!
    I think you have to change the backslash (\) to a slash (/).

```
<?php
    require_once('SplClassLoader.php');

    $loader = new SplClassLoader('Lib', 'Oram/Lib'); 
    $loader->register();

    use Oram\Lib\Classes\Test;
    $test = new Test();
?>
Take a look on [this][1].
```

---

Try that. I have added a \ before your namespace. That could be the answer:

```
$loader = new SplClassLoader('Lib', '\Oram\Lib');
```

Comment: Sorry doesn't work. 

    Fatal error: Class 'Oram\Lib\Classes\Test' not found in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\judyq\index.php on line 10

Comment: Sorry still getting
    Fatal error: Class 'Oram\Lib\Classes\Test' not found in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\judyq\index.php on line 10

Comment: Are you sure you use the right include_path? When not type get_include_path() and show me the output.

Comment: .;C:\php\pear 

There's no php folder there though :-/

Comment: I tried installing pear and using set_include_path() to the pear location and still no joy :(